Are there ionic compounds that dissolve in water but do not dissasociate into their ions?
I would assume such a molecule would be possible because polar ionic compounds have a partial charge that can help them dissolve in water yet not disassociate into their ion parts, but I am not sure.

Yes, e.g. https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2020/cp/c9cp06845g or neutral transition metal complexes.

That depends what you consider an "ionic compound".

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{A_aB_b(s)&<=>\ce{A_aB_b(aq)}} \tag{$K_s$} \
\ce{\ce{A_aB_b(aq)}&<=>aA^b+(aq) +bB^a-(aq)}
\tag{$K_d$} \
\hline
\ce{\ce{A_aB_b(s)}&<=>aA^b+(aq) +bB^a-(aq)}
\tag{$K_{sp}$} \
\end{align}
$$
Partially soluble salts that have a high $K_s$ value but a low $K_d$ value.

$\ce{HgCl2}$ is such a compound. It is soluble in water, but its molecules are rarely dissociated into ions.

According to some Quant Analysis texts magnesium oxalate exists in solution as a molecular compound in equilibrium with ions. This appears to be a kinetic process that reduces with digestion of a solid precipitate. This reaction causes coprecipitation of magnesium oxalate with calcium oxalate in calcium determinations if Calcium oxalate is not separated promptly.

A compound that likes to exist as a molecule is not particularily ionic. Remember that ionic is not a yes/no property.
